# How to decrypt file in python that was decrypted within ars-128-cbc?

Tags: openssl

I have file crypto.txt:
`Salted__x{'b]qJ”‹KM¾>{Kk¬{ÙF6Í‚./óú^²sM}hµÀ—å (¤à§±²·ªºÊa™‘±`A‰§¯*´>c[ÈŒy¯ôEKŸù–sÉ“½ºL6€¶3C’ uÞCßvN`

It was encrypted using aes-128-cbc in OpenSSL. The password is "crypto"

Please can you help to write code so that it can read the ciphertext, decode it and write the plaintext into new file in python3?

I tried to decode it but get an errors with Crypto lib in python.

Comment: When dealing with cryptography, you should read ciphertext as bytes and not as string.
If you give a ciphertext to someone else, better convert bytes to hex first.
Secondly 'crypto' is 6 bytes and aes-128-cbc needs a key of 16 bytes.

So you should read crypto.txt like this: `ct = open('crypto.txt', 'rb').read().hex()`